# How to change Server API CGI/FastCGI to Apache Handler in the bluehost server. Some function are not working in my php configuration

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server, bluehost

I am using PHP 7.0.33 version in the Bluehost server.

Some functions(`Filter_Input`, `header`) are not working in this server while they work perfectly on the other server.

I think this is an issue of CGI/FastCGI.

Because I was using Apache server API handler as I have noticed.

Can someone let me know if this issue of FastCGI? How to resolve this issue. I I am having the issues to change the server API handler FastCGI to Apache. Please help me with this.

Comment: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710817/php-filter-input-not-working) Very similar to your problem

Comment: Did you [check all these issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215576/do-i-need-to-modify-my-bluehost-php-ini-file-header-function-not-working-on-rem)

Comment: Filter_Input function is not working on this server. I think this is the issue of the CGI/FastCGI. Because the same application is working on the two other servers. When I checked the server configuration I got there was the difference of SERVER API. In my old server, the SERVER API is set to 'Apache' while in Bluehost server this is 'CGI/FastCGI'. And everything is working except filter_input. I am not able to get server global variable through filter_input. Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks